# Error when trying to open list with "Open with Access" option

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, microsoft-access

SharePoint 2010 Enterprise with SP2 installed.

We have a standard OOTB SharePoint List and are trying to "Open with Access"[image]

The problem is when we click the "Open with Access" button in the ribbon, we get an error message:

[image]

Can someone please help me figure out how to get rid of this message and allow me to open this list in Access?

Thanks,
-Rounn

Comment: their are couple of reasons for this issue, may be you dont have Office client on the pc or webclient service not running etc...check this http://curah.microsoft.com/27283/to-export-a-list-you-must-have-a-microsoft-sharepoint-foundationcompatible-application-sharepoint-2010-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Thanks, I am able to "Export to Excel" just fine, just not Access. For me, it seems to be related to 64bit Office vs 32bit Office. Still looking into it.

Answer (score 4):

It is one of the limitations Microsoft clearly states as why you should use 32 bit office instead of 64 bit.

- In SharePoint, the list view won’t be available.

See [Choose the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Office](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-Office-2dee7807-8f95-4d0c-b5fe-6c6f49b8d261) on https://support.office.com

And in your bounty you mention

> It currenty only works for 32bit office. The majority of the users I support are on 64 bit Office.

Answer (score 1):

It seems and issue fixed by a hotfix for 32-bit Office.
you can download the hotfix here:

[Hotfix](http://support2.microsoft.com/hotfix/KBHotfix.aspx?kbnum=2553170&kbln=en-US)

Install it and restart you pc.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comment, this is known limitation in Office 64bit. Datasheet view, open with access are not working with office 2010 x64.

Did you try to install [Data Connectivity Components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)? install this on test machine and test it.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Datasheet-view-in-64-bit-Office-2010-f734e938-8baa-492e-84f4-85a7cc85645a?CorrelationId=76a84d60-b81a-4a7d-be8e-dd77a40b660e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

Might want to try in a different browser.. I sometimes get this error in Google Chrome, but it will work fine in Internet Explorer. Not sure why..